# Does the mass of an object modify the wavelength of the waves created if it is dropped in water?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, wavelength

Somebody said me (but can't provide explanation) that if you drop two object (differents masses but same volume) in water (at two different times , the two wavelength are going to be different because the mass of the object.

I think it is false but can't find a valid explanation of whether i'm right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the water wavelength doesn't depend on the source of excitation. However, there are different wave types, [gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) and [capillary waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_wave) propagating at the water surface with different velocities and thus wave lengths. Thus it is possible that a very light object excites mainly capillary waves, which are the small ripples seen on the surface due to the surface tension of water, while a heavy object instead excites the larger amplitude gravity waves which are due to the gravitational force trying to restore deviation from a flat water surface.

Comment: Heavy might give larger amplitude, but why would that affect wavelength (or rather pulse length)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @freecharly. In this case, I think we are in the case of gravity waves. With your answer I make the assumption that if you drop the same object (let's say a aluminium ball, diameter 5cm) from the same height in water and oil, the waves are going to be different wavelength. Am I right ?
And also if I drop, in water, one aluminium cube (5cm side length) and one aluminium ball (5cm diameter), the two object will generate the same gravity waves wavelength ?

Comment: @JBschneider - I think that the wavelengths produced by the falling object are different for gravity waves in water and in oil. And that the gravity wavelengths  produced by dropping  the aluminum ball and cube into water will be the same. There might be a slight difference in amplitude but there is no reason  why they should have different wavelengths.

Comment: Great thank you very much for the answer. It is a lot more clear now.